# ¿Cómo hago para que una función se repita n veces? Python

Tags: python

Quiero que una función se repita el numero de veces que el usuario diga
Ejemplo:

```
def suma():
  a=int(input("Ingrese numero 1 "))
  b=int(input("Ingrese numero 2 "))
  print(a+b)
```

Si quiero que se repita 3 veces seria así :

```
suma()
suma()
suma()
```

Pero yo quiero que la función se repita las veces que el usuario lo indique, pero no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente:

```
print ("Ingrese el numero de veces que desea ejecutar suma(): ")
cant = int(input())       # python 3x
# cant = int(raw_input()) # python 2x

for ejecucion in range(cant):
   suma()
```

- Solicitamos al usuario la cantidad de ejecuciones, importante: convertir la entrada que siempre será una cadena a un entero con `int()`
- Luego con `for ejecucion in range(cant)` implementamos un ciclo que se ejecutará la `cant` de veces ingresada. `range()`genera un rango de valores de 0 a `cant-1`. por cada iteración ejecutamos `suma()`

Comment: gracias por tu explicacion aprendi mucho eres grande

Answer (score 1):

```
print ("numero de veces: ")
n = input()
i=0
while i<n:
suma()
```

siendo n la cantidad de veces ingresada por el usuario e i un contador para que se repita n cantidad de veces la funcion

Comment: por favor mira [answer] y añade una explicación pues respuestas que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad